# logic for handling tie with aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data set:

```
|  ID | TYPE | PERCENT |
------|------|---------|
| 123 |    A |     0.5 |
| 123 |    B |     0.5 |
| 456 |    A |     0.7 |
| 456 |    B |     0.3 |
| 789 |    A |       1 |
```

I would like the following result:

```
|  ID | TYPE | PERCENT |
------|------|---------|
| 123 |    A |     0.5 |
| 456 |    A |     0.7 |
| 789 |    A |       1 |
```

That is, getting the `MAX(percent)` for each `id` and the corresponding `type`.

I'm currently using

```
SELECT ... 
FROM
  (SELECT [id], MAX([percent]) AS [p]
  FROM [highest]
  GROUP BY [id]) a
LEFT JOIN [highest] b 
  ON b.[id] = a.[id]
    AND b.[percent] = a.[p]
```

And getting

```
|  ID |   P | TYPE | PERCENT |
--- --|-----|------|---------|
| 123 | 0.5 |    A |     0.5 |
| 123 | 0.5 |    B |     0.5 |
| 456 | 0.7 |    A |     0.7 |
| 789 |   1 |    A |       1 |
```

Comment: So what's your question? You only want one record per ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT  src.[id], src.[type], src.[percent]
FROM (
    SELECT  [id], [type], [percent], 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY h.[id] ORDER BY [percent] DESC, h.[type] ASC) AS RowNum
    FROM    [highest] h
) src
WHERE src.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: i think this should be `ORDER BY h.[PERCENT] DESC` rather than `ORDER BY h.[type]` since you want highest percentage per id. right? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/140c0/3 unless i misunderstood `:)`

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I had added `DESC` and forgot to mention it. Thanks for updating though.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to skin the cat:

```
SELECT d.ID, m.type, m.[percent]
FROM highest AS d
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 type, [percent]
  FROM highest
  WHERE ID = d.ID
  ORDER BY [percent] DESC, type ASC
) AS m
GROUP BY d.ID, m.type, m.[percent]
;
```

That is, for every distinct `ID`, a row with the maximum (`TOP 1 ... ORDER BY [percent] DESC`) `percent` is fetched. When several types have the maximum for the same ID, the one that sorts before the others (`type ASC`) is selected.

A slightly less verbose equivalent (using DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY):

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.ID, m.type, m.[percent]
FROM highest AS d
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 type, [percent]
  FROM highest
  WHERE ID = d.ID
  ORDER BY [percent] DESC, type ASC
) AS m
;
```

With proper indexing, shouldn't be much worse than [@Bogdan Sahlean's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966606/297408).